# For Angel Broking SmartAPI, does anyone know how to store the NSE live stock market feed coming in JSON file into a dictionary while updating it?

Tags: python, json, function, api

I've been trying to create an algotrade bot in the Angel Broking SmartAPI. I'm getting live data from the API. I'm just confused as to how to store the live data feed that is thrown as output from the API.

```
FEED_TOKEN= feedToken
CLIENT_CODE=clientID
token="nse_cm|3063" # For Vedanta
task="mw"

ss = SmartWebSocket(FEED_TOKEN, CLIENT_CODE)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print("Ticks: {}".format(message))
    
def on_open(ws):
    print("on open")
    ss.subscribe(task,token)
    
def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)
    
def on_close(ws):
    print("Close")

def on_tick(ws, tick):
    print("Ticks: {}".format(tick))

def on_connect():
    print('Connected')
    
# Assign the callbacks.
ss._on_open = on_open
ss._on_connect = on_connect
ss._on_message = on_message
ss._on_error = on_error
ss._on_close = on_close


ss.connect()
```

This is the function that spits the output. Sample of the output is below.

```
Ticks: [{'e': 'nse_cm', 'ltp': '309.85', 'ltq': '56', 'ltt': 'NA', 'name': 'sf', 'tk': '3063'}]
Ticks: [{'name': 'tm', 'tvalue': '10/08/2021 10:41:55'}]
Ticks: [{'e': 'nse_cm', 'ltp': '309.90', 'ltq': '100', 'ltt': 'NA', 'name': 'sf', 'tk': '3063'}]
Ticks: [{'ap': '310.23', 'bp': '309.85', 'bq': '809', 'bs': '6725', 'c': '309.55', 'cng': '00.35', 'e': 'nse_cm', 'lo': '308.10', 'ltp': '309.90', 'ltq': '100', 'ltt': '10/08/2021 10:41:55', 'name': 'sf', 'nc': '00.1131', 'sp': '310.00', 'tbq': '754644', 'tk': '3063', 'to': '677822767.92', 'tsq': '1047420', 'v': '2184904'}]
Ticks: [{'name': 'tm', 'tvalue': '10/08/2021 10:41:56'}]
Ticks: [{'e': 'nse_cm', 'ltp': '309.85', 'ltq': '1', 'ltt': 'NA', 'name': 'sf', 'tk': '3063'}]
Ticks: [{'name': 'tm', 'tvalue': '10/08/2021 10:41:57'}]
Ticks: [{'e': 'nse_cm', 'ltp': '309.85', 'ltq': '95', 'ltt': 'NA', 'name': 'sf', 'tk': '3063'}]
Ticks: [{'name': 'tm', 'tvalue': '10/08/2021 10:41:58'}]
Ticks: [{'ap': '310.23', 'bp': '309.85', 'bq': '150', 'bs': '6725', 'c': '309.55', 'cng': '00.30', 'e': 'nse_cm', 'lo': '308.10', 'ltp': '309.85', 'ltq': '95', 'ltt': '10/08/2021 10:41:56', 'name': 'sf', 'nc': '00.0969', 'sp': '310.00', 'tbq': '748288', 'tk': '3063', 'to': '678133308.15', 'tsq': '1048198', 'v': '2185905'}]
Ticks: [{'e': 'nse_cm', 'ltp': '310.00', 'ltq': '200', 'ltt': 'NA', 'name': 'sf', 'tk': '3063'}]
Ticks: [{'name': 'tm', 'tvalue': '10/08/2021 10:41:59'}]
```

How do I store this data, where I don't know where is the output coming from in the API.
PS. This uses websockets, and you can find the details at

> https://github.com/angelbroking-github/smartapi-python

Documentation Link:

> https://smartapi.angelbroking.com/docs/WebSocketStreaming

Comment: Since its a WS connection, the JSON data coming to you is in real time, ie it gets updated on each tick (where tick can be each second, 10 sec etc)
So for you to store the data in your local, the best approach will be to read each tick, store its in local cache say like redis, or rabbitMQ and then on write this cache data in a SQL DB after every 1 minute, so that there are not too many DB write operations
Your structure can be 
Columns: name, e,  ltp, ltq, ltt, tvalue, ap, bp, bq, bs, c and so on
and each row will have the data of above keys

Comment: Will try it out, @NishantPatel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the data as a variable within the program itself you can append the json data to a list in the on_message function